# Why adding unusable tensors will change the result of an RNN cell in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the simplest code that can reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf

tf.set_random_seed(12345)
np.random.seed(12345)
random.seed(12345)

unusable1 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)
unusable2 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)
unusable3 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 3])

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(5)

changed_data = tf.reduce_sum(cell(X, state = tf.zeros((2, 5)))[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    output = sess.run(changed_data, feed_dict={X: np.ones((2, 3))})
    print(output)   # = -1.46618
```

The result of the above code is `-1.46618` on my machine.

However, if I comment out three unusable constant tensor declarations, the result becomes `1.76918`!

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf

tf.set_random_seed(12345)
np.random.seed(12345)
random.seed(12345)

# unusable1 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)
# unusable2 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)
# unusable3 = tf.constant(1e-3, tf.float32)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 3])

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(5)

changed_data = tf.reduce_sum(cell(X, state = tf.zeros((2, 5)))[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    output = sess.run(changed_data, feed_dict={X: np.ones((2, 3))})
    print(output)   # = 1.76918
```

Actually, you can add/delete/modify constant tensor declarations as much as you like, the result varies quite different!

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializers for variables are getting different op-level seeds because seeding is based on (1) the graph-level seed, and (2) the op id if an op-level seed is not explicitly set (a deterministic function of the previously created ops in the current graph). This prevents every variable from getting exactly the same initialization when a graph-level seed has been set. See [get_seed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/740267f07bcb5a7591eb8a3ab6460c26d56ebdd3/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py#L35) for the implementation.